# Show More Content With AJAX From Server On Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP-HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I want a “load more” button that loads more results using ajax.

Is this possible in AMP-HTML?

I couldn’t find something in the documentation.

I found some resource like amp-list. but it has two problem

1- I must set a height for it,

2- I can not sent `page` number to server per calling ajax.

Is it possible to do it or I must switch to classic pagination?

**My Code is something like this:**

```
<ol class="icon-list full-bottom">
     <li>text1</li>
     <li>text2</li
</ol>
<div id="loadmore"></div>
```

and the json:

```
{
  items: [
    {
       name: "text3"
     },
     ..
   ]
}
```

Comment: You should read the documentation. For example, if you put the `amp-list` at the bottom of the page with an initial height, `amp-runtime` will set the required height. There is ample documentation and illustrations for `more`. Usually the best approach here is RTFM.